# How are multifunctions precisely defined?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, notation

From what I understand, a multifunction is a binary relation between two sets, where each input can be associated with more than one output. For instance, we could define the multifunction $z \mapsto \sqrt z$, which maps every complex number to its two square roots, e.g. $\sqrt{-1}=\{i,-i\}$. I have a couple of questions regarding how multifunctions work and the notation we use to represent them:

1. While a multifunction is often said to ‘associate’ an input to one or more outputs, in another sense there is only a single output, namely a single set of values. Hence, I don’t quite understand why people say that ‘a multifunction is not a function’ (in the traditional sense of the word).
2. The complex logarithm is an example of a multifunction: since the exponential function is periodic, every non-zero complex number has infinitely many logarithms. When people say $i\pi$ is *a* logarithm of $-1$, do they simply mean that $i\pi$ is one of the solutions to $\exp z=-1$, or do they mean that $i\pi \in \log(-1)$? In other words, does saying that $i\pi$ is *a* logarithm of $-1$ imply that we are defining $\log$ as a multifunction, or does it simply acknowledge that $-1$ is one of the solutions to the equation $\exp z=-1$? Does this vary according to context?
3. Instead of $\sqrt{-1}= \{i,-i\}$, I have seen written $\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$. Isn’t this an abuse of notation? After all, saying that the square roots of $-1$ are a *set* of values seems to be different to saying that $\sqrt{-1}$ is equal to both $i$ and $-i$ at the same time (in particular, the latter does not seem to make much sense, since it would imply that $i=-i$).
4. In complex analysis, how common is it to work with multifunctions as opposed to single-valued functions? Is there a reason for why mathematicians prefer one over the over? I understand that this might greatly according to context.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Re 1 the usual definition of a function $A \to B$ does not admit the possibility of a "set of values" other than a singleton in $B$ as an output. Re 2 it is sometimes difficult to parse what people mean when they say $a$ is a logarithm of $b$; at a minimum it means that $e^a = b$ but they may not have thought through this (e.g. they may not have defined a logarithm function). 3. Yes it's an abuse of notation; $\sqrt{-1}$ itself is often an abuse of notation. 4. Fairly uncommon, often one expands the domain of the function to a Riemann surface and deals with a single valued function on that.

Comment: @leslie: Thanks, this is a very helpful explanation. I have two questions: (a) what is the usual definition of a function that you are referring to? I understand that often a function is defined as a set of ordered pairs of numbers, but this definition is probably not broad enough in this case. (b) when you say that $\sqrt{-1}$ is an abuse of notation, are you referring to when people write that $i=\sqrt{-1}$, not when you define the square root as a multifunction?

Comment: A multifunction is not a function in the sense that it is not a function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. There are several solutions: (a) Change the codomain, i.e. consider functions $\mathbb{C} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$ (the power set); you might want to restrict the codomain to discrete, non-empty subsets instead of arbitrary subsets. The problem is that it becomes much harder to talk about continuity, differentiability etc.; things you might expect from a ‘function’. (b) Change the domain, i.e. consider functions on suitably defined Riemann surfaces instead. The trouble here is that …

Comment: … this is more involved in that you have to define Riemann surfaces first and in that you have to track how your new function relates to the old. (I.e. $\exp$ has codomain $\mathbb{C}$; if $\log$ is defined on some Riemann surface $X$ instead, in what sense is it the inverse of $\exp$?

Comment: In complex analysis there are no multifunctions or multivalued functions or whatever, only analytic continuations of analytic functions. When continuing $\log(z)$ counterclockwise along a circle around $0$ we get $\log(z)+2i\pi$. Is it clear to you?

Comment: @Joe, the "usual definition" I had in mind was that a function $f: A \to B$ is a subset of $A \times B$ with the property that for each $a \in A$ there is exactly one $b \in B$ with $(a,b) \in f$. As you say, it immediately invites generalization, but people often avoid multivalued functions by changing what $A$ and $B$ are. Re $\sqrt{-1}$, yes, I mean just writing $i = \sqrt{-1}$ (and not e.g. being more careful about it). Sometimes it's written like that on page $1$ of a complex analysis book!  Seems like the wrong way to begin a book on those kinds of issues. But what do I know.

Comment: @reuns: I'm surprised that you say that 'there are no multifunctions' in complex analysis. What exactly do you mean by this? From what I understand, it makes sense to define $z^w$ as $\{\exp(wr),\exp r = z\}$. Then, if we want we like, we can choose a branch of the logarithm, so that $z^w$ becomes a well-defined function.

Comment: Choose one branch of $\log$ analytic at $a$ then $f(z)=\exp(w\log(z))$ is analytic at $a$ and the other branches are its analytic continuations along curves $a\to ?$ not passing through $0$. Nothing multivalued in there.

Comment: @reuns: I understand that this might be a more common and/or more desirable approach. But isn't defining $z^w$ in the way I described still possible?

Comment: @reuns The analytic continuation viewpoint certainly is valid and (depending on what you want to do) might even be the best approach; however, it is far from the only approach. (For example, it involves having to make choices when solving equations/inverting functions which might be undesirable.) Both multivalued functions and Riemann surfaces are common and valid alternatives that illuminate other aspects of the theory. Clawing that they don’t exist is misleading, in my opinion.

Comment: @EikeSchulte No, it is the multivalued stuff which is misleading. Riemann surfaces  are a natural topic having nothing to do with multivaluedness. The set of all analytic continuations of a function always define a Riemann surface.

Comment: Saying that $\log$ holomorphic $\Bbb{C^*\to C/2i\pi Z}$ is multivalued is misleading, this is specific to $\log$, it doesn't generalize (try with $(z-1)\log z$). Even $z^w :\Bbb{C^*\to C^*}/\langle e^{2i\pi w}\rangle$ fails when $w$ is a real irrational.

Comment: @leslie: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I have one more question, if you don’t mind. Earlier, you said that functions (in the conventional sense of the word) do not output sets, unless that set happens to be a singleton. If functions are supposed to spit out numbers, then I don’t see how a singleton would be an admissible output. After all, the set $\{2\}$ seems different to the number $2$. So why are conventional functions allowed to output singletons, but not sets in general?

Comment: Whoops. I didn't mean to say that functions output singletons. Only that if $f: A \to B$ is a function then for any $a$ in $A$, the set of outputs $\{b \in B: (a,b) \in f\}$ is a singleton. Which isn't to say that $f(a)$ is that set (as you note, $f(a)$ would in this case be $b$ and not $\{b\}$). Does that clear it up?

Comment: @leslietownes: Yes, I think it does, as long as I am not misunderstanding what you're saying. So $\{b \in B \mid (a,b) \in f\}=\{b\}$, since by definition the first entry of the ordered pair $(a,b)$ uniquely defines the second entry (otherwise we wouldn't be dealing with a function).